# Difficulty understanding a PHP array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to manipulate an array that was generated from a MySQL query.  The print_r format returns the following:

> Array ( [cols] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => time [type] => number ) [1] => Array ( [label] => quantity [type] => number ) ) [rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => 8.8 ) [1] => Array ( [v] => 3 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => **8.2** ) [1] => Array ( [v] => **4** ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => 7.3 ) [1] => Array ( [v] => 1 ) ) ) [3] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => 5.7 ) [1] => Array ( [v] => 3 ) ) ) [4] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => 4.9 ) [1] => Array ( [v] => 2 ) ) ) [5] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => 2.9 ) [1] => Array ( [v] => 1 ) ) ) [6] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => 1.6 ) [1] => Array ( [v] => 1 ) ) ) ) )

I put this output into the array beautifier here in order to better understand the structure: http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/

However, even with this prettier version, I'm unsure how to access specific elements.  For example, how would I return just the pair of "8.2","4" bolded above from this array?  Any insight into this structure would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code that generated this array:

```
$return_structure = array(
    'cols' => array (
       // array('label' => 'name', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'time', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'quantity', 'type' => 'number')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $return_structure['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        //array('v' => $row['name']),
        array('v' => $row['time']),
        array('v' => $row['quantity']),
            ));
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!!
-Daniel

Comment: Can we see how you are retrieving your data with the PHP and the SQL Query?

Comment: $return_structure = array(
    'cols' => array (
       // array('label' => 'name', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'time', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'quantity', 'type' => 'number')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $return_structure['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        //array('v' => $row['name']),
        array('v' => $row['time']),
        array('v' => $row['quantity']),
            ));

Comment: ummmm sorry for the poor format in the comment, I'm not sure how to paste in clean code blocks here    thank you for the quick response

Comment: Just edit your question, and I am looking for the mysql_query or whatever you used to retrieve the data from the database

Comment: try printing inside of a `<pre>` tag if you're debugging with prints. It should keep whitespace and `print_r` will have correct formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to get a "pretty" view quickly is to view it in your web browser using the [html "pre" tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

When accessing a multi dimensional associative array, you can either:

1) use a loop to go through everything, and you may need nested loops to accomplish this. Even using a bunch of [foreach loops](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) this could get quite messy and cumbersome.

something like:

```
foreach ($arrayDImension as $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray as $row -> $value) {
      //access the rows & values here
    }
}
```

OR

2) access them directly , assuming you know the names of the indexes, etc. You could access them like this:

```
print_r($array['rows'][3]['c'][0]['v']); // gives you 8.2

print_r($array['rows'][4]['c'][5]['v']); //gives you 4
```